Angular - Using cdkListBox to create multi selection component
I am using the following example to create a multiselect listbox.
Example
I commented out image file for the selection indicator since I dont need it.
.example-option[aria-selected='true']::before {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 width: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 /* background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg 
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="24"><path d="m9.55 18-5.7-5.7 
 1.425-1.425L9.55 15.15l9.175-9.175L20.15 7.4Z"/></svg>'); */
 /* stylelint-disable-line */
 background-size: cover;
 position: absolute;
 left: 2px;

}
However, I dont know how to get multi selection back. Ideally, I want to toggle a row selection by clicking on it with CTRL down. Any idea where to go from here?
Thanks
